# Sybase 12.5-BDE-ADO "where myColumn=null" failure

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-xe, sap-ase, delphi-5

We have an old application that reads in SQL text files and sends them to Sybase ASE 12.51. Our legacy app was written in Delphi 5 and is using the BDE TQuery component for this process and accessing Sybase with the BDE SQLinks for Sybase.

Pseudo code:

```
SQLText=readSQLFile;
aTQuery.SQL.add(SQLText);
aTQuery.ExecSQL;
```

Recently we moved our DB access layer to the Delphi XE ADO implementation - TADOQuery, using the Sybase supplied ADO provider, still using same model:

```
SQLText=readSQLFile;
aTADOQuery.SQL.add(SQLText)
aTADOQuery.ExecSQL;
```

After migrating to ADO, we discovered that certain data was missing. We traced the failure to this SQL construct:

```
Select myColumn from myTable 
Where  tranID = null
```

Knowing that this construct is sematically questionable at best, I did a 'double take' when I saw this code, but Sybase 12.5 accepts it  - however using ADO, this segment fails.

**We decided to change:**

```
Where  tranID = null
```

**to**

```
Where  tranID is null
```

**Then the missing data was loaded - problem solved, for this segment and several others as well.**

***Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior? Where/why did ADO apparently intercept and reject this seqment whereas the BDE passed it thru?***

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"NULL" has a very special meaning, and SQL needs a special handling. You can't compare a value to "NULL", that's why there is the special operator IS (NOT) NULL to check for it. An exhaustive explanation would take some space, here a simple explanation.

From a "mathematical" point of view, NULL can be thought as "infinity". You can't compare two infinite values easily, for example think about the set of integer numbers and even numbers. Both are infinite, but it seems logical the former is larger than the latter. All you can say IS both sets are infinite.

That's also helps to explain for example why 1 + NULL returns NULL and so on (usually only aggregate functions like SUM() ecc. may ignore NULL values - ignore, not turn NULLs into zeroes).

This metaphor may not hold true in sorting, because some databases choose to consider NULL less than any value (some kind of -infinity and thereby returning them first in ascending order), other the other way round. Some have an option to set where to return NULLs.

Check your database documentation about NULL arithmetics and NULL comparisons. field = NULL should have never been used, don't know if Sybase accepts it, but most SQL implementations don't, and I guess it is not SQL standards compliant. It is far better to get used to the IS (NOT) NULL syntax.

**Update**: Sybase has a "set ansinull" option, from the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug95.htm) (always RTFM!), in 12.5.1 it was expanded to disallow the '= NULL' syntax (when set to ON to make it compliant with SQL standards). When set to OFF '= NULL' works as 'IS NULL'.

Maybe the SQL Links or the ADO provider set it to one value or the other.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the question - see edit. BTW, I also compare Null to Infinity in some respects - it's not a value - perhaps better characterized as a 'state' (the state of having  no state...) but this can get really academic and I don't think this is an academic forum - it's for people with 'real jobs' LOL

Comment: I was explaining why the correct syntax works and the other one should be always avoided.
Anyway did you switched from BDE to ADO **only**? Or did you changed something else? Both access layer should not parse the query at all, but could set different client options. Is the database the same? Is the client the same? Drivers can have different "compatibility" settings. Did you check SQL Links parameters?

Comment: For example, check the "set ansinull" option... guess this is a case of "RTFM!" :) Maybe one set it to off and the other to on by default.

Comment: Agreed - I would never write '=null' and it should be **BANNED**. My new code runs against the same database, but entirely under ADO - legacy code runs SQLinks but I'm not sure how it's configured - have to coordinate with the guys who know the legacy code better - I've been using ADO for years and years and never actually used SQLinks in any prod situation.

Comment: "Maybe the SQL Links or the ADO provider set it to one value or the other" - more likely the legacy code is setting "set ansinull" to "OFF" but the way I connect through ADO this isn't being done - the option can be set on a per session basis. I'm giving you the points because you have taken the time and pointed us in the right direction. Regardless, the solution is of course simply not to use '=null', which is semantically incorrect. As I go through our files, this construct will be summarily removed.